# Show that the mixed partial derivatives of the function are not equal

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Show that the mixed partial derivatives of the function $f(x,y) = \frac{x^3y-xy^3}{x^2+y^2}$ if $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$ are not equal. I found both $\frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}$, and they both came out to the solution $\frac{x^6+9x^4y^2-9x^2y^4-y^6}{(x^2+y^2)^3}$. I even checked this in an online calculator. Why is the question asking to prove them unequal if they come out to be equal? What am I missing?

Comment: you were probably meant to find the mixed partials at $0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

To begin with, notice that

\begin{align*}
f(x,y) = \frac{x^{3}y - xy^{3}}{x^{2} + y^{2}} & \Rightarrow \ln f(x,y) = \ln(x^{3}y - xy^{3}) - \ln(x^{2} + y^{2})\\\\
& \Rightarrow \frac{\partial \ln f(x,y)}{\partial x} = \frac{3x^{2}y - y^{3}}{x^{3}y - xy^{3}} - \frac{2x}{x^{2} + y^{2}}\\\\
& \Rightarrow \frac{\partial_{x}f(x,y)}{f(x,y)} = \frac{3x^{2}y - y^{3}}{x^{3}y - xy^{3}} - \frac{2x}{x^{2} + y^{2}}\\\\
& \Rightarrow \partial_{x}f(x,y) = f(x,y)\left[\frac{3x^{2}y - y^{3}}{x^{3}y - xy^{3}} - \frac{2x}{x^{2} + y^{2}}\right]
\end{align*}

Similarly, one has that

\begin{align*}
f(x,y) = \frac{x^{3}y - xy^{3}}{x^{2} + y^{2}} & \Rightarrow \ln f(x,y) = \ln(x^{3}y - xy^{3}) - \ln(x^{2} + y^{2})\\\\
& \Rightarrow \frac{\partial\ln f(x,y)}{\partial y} = \frac{x^{3} - 3xy^{2}}{x^{3}y - xy^{3}} - \frac{2y}{x^{2} + y^{2}}\\\\
& \Rightarrow \frac{\partial_{y}f(x,y)}{f(x,y)} = \frac{x^{3} - 3xy^{2}}{x^{3}y - xy^{3}} - \frac{2y}{x^{2} + y^{2}}\\\\
& \Rightarrow \partial_{y}f(x,y) = f(x,y)\left[\frac{x^{3} - 3xy^{2}}{x^{3}y - xy^{3}} - \frac{2y}{x^{2} + y^{2}}\right]
\end{align*}

Now you can take the difference, whence we get that
\begin{align*}
\partial_{x}f(x,y) - \partial_{y}f(x,y) & = f(x,y)\left[\frac{(3x^{2}y + 3xy^{2}) - (x^{3} + y^{3})}{x^{3}y - xy^{3}} + \frac{2(y-x)}{x^{2} + y^{2}}\right]
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Doesn't this difference not being zero show that they are not equal? since if they were equal it would be 0

Comment: That's the point.